# How to Get Rich Text field in Plugin?

Tags: plugins

I have a 'details' rich text field in my User section. How can i get it in my plugin controller in an array.
I tried getting it by

```
 $userInfo[] = array(
  'username' => $user->name,
  'details' => $user->details,
)
```

I get an array like this

```
        Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [username] => Username
                [details] => Craft\RichTextData Object
                    (
                        [_pages:Craft\RichTextData:private] => 
                        [_rawContent:Craft\RichTextData:private] => Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text
                        [content:protected] => Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text
                        [charset:protected] => UTF-8
                    )
                )
            )
```

Comment: Haha. "How to get rich..." made me smile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got It through ->

```
$userInfo[] = array(
  'username' => $user->name,
  'details' =>  (string) $user->details,
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd be inclined to use the public methods for this.
$user->detail->getRawContent();
or
$user->detail->getParsedContent();
etc.

Comment: This is more precise response.